# How to import or copy worksheets from different workbook in one workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I just started learning VBA so please advise.

I have one Macro(master workbook) where I would like to import/copy worksheets from 5 different workbook.

So each of these 5 workbook contain different sheets out of which i would like to import/copy only one or particular sheets. These imported sheets should be marked as "Sheet 1(for data from workbook 1), Sheet 2(for data from workbook 2) and similarly in master workbook.

I have all of this Workbooks in one folder. This folder changes every week so i cannot give folder path. Rather i want the flexibility to Browse folder.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: While I'm loath to recommend the recorder, did you try it to give you an idea of syntax required? Try it, mess around with it to work the problems for a while, then publish up what its giving you. At that point your issues can be explained and tackled.

Comment: I wouldn't loathe the recorder at all! It's a great tool for discovering the functions and methods required for specific actions in excel. Its certainly better than paging through the MS Docs looking for a single function that might not even exist in VBA. You just have to learn how to change specific range references into dynamic references and remove Select / Selection.

Answer (score 2):

Example code of how to import all the sheets from an external workbook with browser:

```
   Sub shCopy()
    Dim fName As String, wb As Workbook
    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
        For Each sh In wb.Sheets
            sh.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next
        wb.Close False
    End Sub
```

Now you just need to specify the conditions on what sheet to actually copy, and name it accordingly.

Pretty sure we shouldn't be adding questions as answers. Next time you should probably make a new question.

But I can't see much deviation between the loops, and you are on the right track. But you don't actually need the `If` since everything within the loop will repeat each loop anyway.
The number for the file dialouge can be inserted with the `i` variable using the `&` operator.

```
Sub shCopy()
Dim fName As String, wb As Workbook, i As Integer
For i = 1 To 3
    MsgBox "Select file " & i
    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("mymacro.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("mymacro.xlsm").Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet" & Sheets.Count
    wb.Close False
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Christofer
Could you help me with following?